# CSS Translate snaps back on Hover Off even using inline-block

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a Rails 5 application with:

1. Bootstrap (uses jQuery)
2. SASS
3. Bourbon

```css
.align-middle {
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}

.text-muted {
  color: #6c757d !important;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center !important;
}

.badge-info {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #17a2b8;
  border-color: #17a2b8;
}

.domain-info-group {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6.5em;
  height: 6.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-30%, -30%);
  transform: translate(-30%, -30%);
}

.domain-cluster {
  width: 50em;
  height: 50em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-30%, -30%);
  transform: translate(-30%, -30%);
}

.domain-name {
  opacity: 0;
}

.domain-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1.6em;
  height: 1.6em;
  font-size: 4em;
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0);
  transform: translate(0);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.1s;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(1) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(1) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-10em, 0em);
  transform: translate(-10em, 0em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.2s;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(2) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(2) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(10em, 0em);
  transform: translate(10em, 0em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.3s;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(3) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(3) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0em, -10em);
  transform: translate(0em, -10em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.4s;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(4) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(4) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0em, 10em);
  transform: translate(0em, 10em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.5s;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(5) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(5) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-7.5em, -7.5em);
  transform: translate(-7.5em, -7.5em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.6s;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(6) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(6) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(7.5em, -7.5em);
  transform: translate(7.5em, -7.5em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.7s;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(7) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(7) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(7.5em, 7.5em);
  transform: translate(7.5em, 7.5em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.8s;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(8) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(8) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-7.5em, 7.5em);
  transform: translate(-7.5em, 7.5em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.9s;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(9) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(9) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="domain-cluster">
  <div class="domain-info-group text-center">
    <div class="domain-circle badge-info text-center align-middle" data-value="2">
      Pe
    </div>
    <div class="domain-name text-muted">
      Personal
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="domain-info-group text-center">
    <div class="domain-circle badge-info text-center align-middle" data-value="3">
      Fa
    </div>
    <div class="domain-name text-muted">
      Family
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="domain-info-group text-center">
    <div class="domain-circle badge-info text-center align-middle" data-value="4">
      Wo
    </div>
    <div class="domain-name text-muted">
      Work
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="domain-info-group text-center">
    <div class="domain-circle badge-info text-center align-middle" data-value="5">
      Sp
    </div>
    <div class="domain-name text-muted">
      Spiritual
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm doing this https://jsfiddle.net/stoicAlchemist/4ptz0wvn/ and, as you can see, the transformation when on hover works fine but when on Hover Off, it just snaps back to the original position. I've been searching for a similar question but can't seem to find a close enough question that explains my confusion, I even tried the `inline-block` on the `display` property and it's not working, it has to be something dumb and I'm not seeing it. Anyone has a clue on the why the translation back is not working with a transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything Hunter Fraizer said gave me the clue to where was the issue here. Apparently, adding a `:hover` to a selector means that the transform will take place once it's hover over it, but when it's not, the transformation doesn't take place so it is necessary to add a transformation "back to the origin", which I did by adding the transition so it's not just "translated back in a blink". Please check out the original link for the jsfiddle to get the updated version.

```css
.align-middle {
  vertical-align: middle !important;
}
.text-muted {
  color: #6c757d !important;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center !important;
}
.badge-info {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #17a2b8;
  border-color: #17a2b8;
}
.domain-info-group {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6.5em;
  height: 6.5em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-30%, -30%);
          transform: translate(-30%, -30%);
  transition: all 1s ease-out 0.1s
}

.domain-cluster {
  width: 50em;
  height: 50em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 30%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-30%, -30%);
          transform: translate(-30%, -30%);
}

.domain-name {
  opacity: 0;
}

.domain-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1.6em;
  height: 1.6em;
  font-size: 4em;
  transition: box-shadow 1.2s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0);
          transform: translate(0);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.1s;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(1) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(1) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-10em, 0em);
          transform: translate(-10em, 0em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.2s;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(2) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(2) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(10em, 0em);
          transform: translate(10em, 0em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.3s;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(3) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(3) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0em, -10em);
          transform: translate(0em, -10em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.4s;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(4) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(4) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0em, 10em);
          transform: translate(0em, 10em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.5s;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(5) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(5) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-7.5em, -7.5em);
          transform: translate(-7.5em, -7.5em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.6s;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(6) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(6) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(7.5em, -7.5em);
          transform: translate(7.5em, -7.5em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.7s;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(7) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(7) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(7.5em, 7.5em);
          transform: translate(7.5em, 7.5em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.8s;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(8) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(8) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-7.5em, 7.5em);
          transform: translate(-7.5em, 7.5em);
  transition: all 1s ease 0.9s;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(9) .domain-name {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.domain-cluster:hover .domain-info-group:nth-child(9) .domain-circle {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="domain-cluster">
  <div class="domain-info-group text-center">
    <div class="domain-circle badge-info text-center align-middle" data-value="2"> 
      Pe
    </div>
    <div class="domain-name text-muted">
      Personal
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="domain-info-group text-center">
    <div class="domain-circle badge-info text-center align-middle" data-value="3"> 
      Fa
    </div>
    <div class="domain-name text-muted">
      Family
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="domain-info-group text-center">
    <div class="domain-circle badge-info text-center align-middle" data-value="4"> 
      Wo
    </div>
    <div class="domain-name text-muted">
      Work
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="domain-info-group text-center">
    <div class="domain-circle badge-info text-center align-middle" data-value="5"> 
      Sp
    </div>
    <div class="domain-name text-muted">
      Spiritual
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you're hovering away from. If you set your `body` tag or outermost wrapper to `position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%` along with `body:hover .domain-cluster .domain-info-group:nth-child(n) .domain-circle` the animation remains in tact UNTIL the mouse leaves the browser window. After it leaves the browser the CSS has no choice but to revert back to its original state since the :hover state is only temporary, as implied by the name (you are no longer hovering). Same with :active and :focus, they are unaware of the context of anything once the mouse leaves the browser. There is no data being binded to the DOM.

You could possibly achieve this effect using purely CSS by using some sort of animation-delay on one of your animations e.g. setting it to a super high value that will not expire before the mouse re-enters the window. But it would be much simpler to throw in a line or two of JS that adds some sort of .blur class to the elements once the mouse leaves the window (which in turn could negate the inherited styles that are forcing your animation back to its original state)

Comment: The hover target is the .domain-cluster, apparently the size was taking the whole preview on the jsFiddle, I've fixed the size and put a bigger container to demonstrate the error. As this is a transformation, this is no related to animations. If you try again, you can lower your mouse and see it leave the `.domain-cluster` still inside the window and snap the position back without transition

Comment: Sure the animation would be permanent had you not applied it to the :hover state selector. But I now see what you're talking about. The cause of this is essentially the DOM isn't aware of the viewport's complete size due to weird css height quirks. I fixed the issue by replace all **.domain-cluster:hover with body:hover .domain-cluster**, and making sure the body had height:100%; min-height:100% as well.,

Comment: only to demonstrate the issue and show you that the height isn't a limiting factor here. The issue is the DOM's calculating of the viewport's height and the addition of the :hover state selector, which applies temporary styling only on hover. The iframe didn't specify any particular body height styling, so it was simply basing the entire viewport's height on the non-body rendered content, which in your case were the circles, which had an inherent height of only ~half the page height. Everything will still collapse once the mouse leaves the viewport though

Comment: Whoops I meant set html to height:100%, not body! That's the weird quirk. Things might have changed in recent times, or at least some other ways to avoid this issue. But for now simple add **html {height:100%;min-height:100%}**  -it's pretty safe and compatible I believe

Comment: here's an example I came up with that allows for transition delays and dynamic height containment so you don't have to apply silly body:hover and crap like that. hope this helps https://jsfiddle.net/kLrj8twe/

Comment: I thought about what you said and I think you are right on the DOM not being aware of the viewport's things and I figured out, I already fixed it, the issue was that, as you said, the transformation is done on the :hover but nothing is said on the hover-off, which means I need a transformation exactly the same with a transition to the point of origin, so I've added it and now works :) thank you for your help, Will add the answer and credit you with the idea